# matplotlib format offset string

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, format

So I am looking to simply format the offset string (at least that is what i think it is called, see image) that matplotlib places along with an axis that has been set to show tick labels in scientific notation, but where the range is less than one order of magnitude (power of 10).

here is what I am talking about:
[image]
Essentially, how do I make it bigger/coloured?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `ax.yaxis.get_offset_text()` to access the offset text. You can then set the size and color on that `Text` object. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10),np.linspace(0,1e11,10))

offset_text = ax.yaxis.get_offset_text()

offset_text.set_size(20)
offset_text.set_color('red')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for such a concise and on point answer. Exactly what I was looking for.