# Matplotlib/Pyplot - Format Auto Scaling Factor

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a diagram, as shown below, where the x-axis has a very small unit.

Pyplot creates an auto-offset and scaling factor, shown in small text at the bottom right of the plot, reading: 1e-9+2e1.

How can I set a formatter and fontsize for this scaling value?

My current Latex-style formatter is provided below:

```
def LatexFormat(value, scirange=[0.01,1000]):
    if(np.abs(value)>scirange[0] and np.abs(value)<scirange[1]):
       float_str = r"${:3.3f}$".format(value)
    else:
       try:
           float_str = "{:3.3E}".format(value)
           base, exponent = float_str.split("E")
           float_str = r"${0} \times 10^{{{1}}}$".format(base, int(exponent))
       except:
           float_str=str(value)
    return float_str
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib format offset string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748347/matplotlib-format-offset-string)